# Angular hide element based on id

Tags: angular

I want to be able to show/hide element based on its id.
I got a dynamic list that has following data structure in TS component:

```
vehicles =   [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "type": "car",
          "brand": "toyota",
          "model": "rav4",
          "properties": {
            "doors": "4",
            "seats": "4"
          }
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "type": "car",
          "brand": "ford",
          "model": "mustang",
          "properties": {
            "doors": "2",
            "seats": "2"
          }
        }
      ];
```

in the html:

```
<div *ngFor="let vehicle of vehicles">
    {{vehicle.id | json}}
    {{vehicle.type| json}}
    {{vehicle.brand| json}}
    {{vehicle.model| json}}

    <button (click)="fn(vehicle.id)">Toggle Properties</button>

    <div [id]="'prop'+vehicle.id">
            Vehicle Properties
            <br>
            {{vehicle.properties | json}}
    </div>
</div>
```

This is a approach i am trying to figure out to apply.

- Find out the elements ID (in this case would be something like "prop1" or "prop2"
- Find out if the element is hidden or not
- Apply opposite of its hidden status

So far haven't been lucky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create an array (e.g. `vehiclePropVisible`) to keep track of the visibility of each property element, and operate on it using the array index instead of the vehicle id.

[Working CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/serverless-wildflower-invxz?)

The array would need to be reinitialized each time `vehicleData` changes.

**ts-file:**

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

interface VehicleData {
  id: number;
  type: string;
  brand: string;
  model: string;
  properties: {
    doors: number;
    seats: number;
  };
}

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  vehicleData: VehicleData[] = [
    {
      id: 1,
      type: "car",
      brand: "toyota",
      model: "rav4",
      properties: {
        doors: 4,
        seats: 4
      }
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      type: "car",
      brand: "ford",
      model: "mustang",
      properties: {
        doors: 2,
        seats: 2
      }
    }
  ];

  vehiclePropVisible = this.vehicleData.map(() => false);

  togglePropVisible(i: number): void {
    this.vehiclePropVisible[i] = !this.vehiclePropVisible[i];
  }
}
```

**html-file:**

```
<div>
  <div *ngFor="let vehicle of vehicleData; let i = index">
    {{vehicle.id}} {{vehicle.type}} {{vehicle.brand}} {{vehicle.model}}

    <button (click)="togglePropVisible(i)">Toggle Properties</button>

    <div *ngIf="vehiclePropVisible[i]">
      Vehicle Properties
      <br />
      Doors: {{vehicle.properties.doors}} Seats: {{vehicle.properties.seats}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes that what i have atm as well.  I was hoping to find a solution that doesn't rely on intermediate array

Comment: I'm pretty sure saving states in the DOM-tree is not recommended in angular, but you can of course set an id on the element you want to show/hide, and set the style in a method. See this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-banach-nzejm?) I made.

Comment: Saving in DOM-tree is not best idea when it comes to angular, so i'm avoiding it. I was hoping i had missed something obvious that angular api's handle, hence why i started looking into [hidden]. However [hidden] only plays around with CSS settings.

Answer (score 1):

Use *ngIf in the div you want to hide

```
 <div *ngIf="vehicle.showProperties" [id]="'prop'+vehicle.id"></div>
```

and toggle the 'showProperties' flag of vehicle on button click

```
 <button (click)="vehicle.showProperties = !vehicle.showProperties">Toggle Properties</button>
```

NOTE: if you using the interface on array then put the 'showProperties' in the interface otherwise make the array 'any' type.

eg. vehicles: any = [ // your vehicle data]

[Here is the stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-n4zhjh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) link of working demo

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem, all it does is shows/hides ALL properties divs, what i am after is to hide the one with specific ID

Comment: What do you mean by specific Id? I don't see any id in the properties object, can you explain this a bit more clearly? Do you want to hide the whole vehicle?

Comment: Have a look at the HTML code, there is a div that has a generated id "<div [id]="'prop'+vehicle.id">".

Comment: Have you even tried the code I added here, it will only hide the propertied of specific vehicle the button clicked for, not for all the vehicle. I recommend you to please try before commenting anything

Comment: Simple, where do you get showProperties from? Coz that doesn't exist anywhere in the test code i shown you. Are you making assumptions or are you missing a piece of code? If showProperties was part of the result set, then yes your piece of code will work, but without it it doesn't work.

Comment: the showProperties is a new key value pair in the vehicle's object, by default the key will not be there in the object and if the showProperties 
 doesn't exists in the object, if will be considered as false and once you clicked the toggle button, the showProperties flag will be added into the object automatically. You doesn't need to add any other code for this property.

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work like that, i've event tried it just to make sure, "Property 'showProperties' does not exist on type" is the error message that gets sent back. I've created a stackblitz to show this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bhtsbs?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: If you are using interface for array type then add this to the interface or if not then add type 'any' to the the  array of vehicles eg.

 vehicles: any = [ // your vehicle data]

Comment: added the stackblitz link to the working demo of your code.

Comment: Yes, your approach of using any will now enable your answer to work. I recommend updating your answer to call that out as its a important piece of code.